# C# Selenium can't get console log type info

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to export all the information from the chrome console to c# project. it's working for error and warning but not for info log type.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
options.AddArgument(@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User 
Data");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
var entries = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
Console.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
}
```

Any idea ?